# How to make range search in multidimentional php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array where I need to  some range values like : I want to search from 10,000 to 20,000
Array example is given below :

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample1
        [price] => 10000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample1
        [price] => 18000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample1
        [price] => 22000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample1
        [price] => 14000
    )

   )
```

How I can get selected range of values from array.

Comment: You're unclear about what you are asking. What do you mean by `I want to search from 10,000 to 20,000 Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filterArray($search_array, $min, $max)
{
    $returned_array = [];
    foreach($search_array as $array_item)
    {
        $price = $array_item["price"];
        if($price >= $min && $price <= $max) $returned_array[] = $array_item;
    }
    return $returned_array;
}
```

This will return a filtered array given your min and max values

Answer (score 2):

Using [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$min = 10000;
$max = 20000;
$selectedRange = array_filter(
    $myOriginalArray,
    function ($value) use ($min, $max) {
        return (($value >= $min) && ($value <= $max));
    }
);
```

Though if this data is coming from a database query, it would be better do filter it there using a WHERE clause

Comment: Actually I the value coming from API source not any database and exact array data is multidimensional array.

Comment: Well if the API source allows filtering in the queries you make to that, use it; otherwise the code above should still work for the array structure that you've posted

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, the best answere I can give you is writing something like array_walk for this.
The second offere (if you need to do other operations with the new array) is to use array_filter, as shown in the buttom.

```
<?php

$min = 14000;
$max = 19000;

function array_walk_example($item, $key)
{
    global $min,$max;
    if ($item["price"] > $min && $item["price"] < $max){
        echo $key. $item["price"]."<br />\n";
    }
}

$array = Array
  (
      0 => Array
    (
        "name" => "sample1",
        "price" => 10000
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        "name" => "sample2",
        "price" => 18000
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        "name" => "sample3",
        "price" => 22000
    ),

3 => Array
    (
        "name" => "sample4",
        "price" => 14000
    ),

);

array_walk($array, "array_walk_example");

function array_filter_example($value){
    global $min,$max;
var_dump($value);
        return (($value['price'] >= $min) && ($value['price'] <= $max));

}

$range = array_filter($array,"array_filter_example");
var_dump($range);
```